# xargs kill: Failure

Tags: linux, unix, kill

Consider the following command:

```
ps ax | ack -i "[p]rocessname" | awk '{print $1}'
```

This lists the PID's of the processes matching `processname`.

When I attempt to kill each of these processes like this,

```
ps ax | ack -i "[p]rocessname" | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill
```

I get the following errors:

```
kill: 90632: Operation not permitted
kill: 90642: Operation not permitted
kill: 90724: Operation not permitted
kill: 90732: Operation not permitted
```

I'm thinking xargs might be treating the pids as Strings instead of integers or something in that manner. Or perhaps I should use `cut` instead of `awk` here (I'm new to `awk`). Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command is fine. You simply don't have permission to kill the processes returned by `awk`. In Unix, only the `root` user can kill processes owned by another user.

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing that out! I will modify the command accordingly.